# Editing product page with dimsav/laravel-translatable

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, translation

im using a package called [Laravel-Translatable](https://github.com/dimsav/laravel-translatable)

but is giving me more problemns that i expect, mainly with quite simple tasks. For example i have a list of all records (products), and each of them haves 2 languages translated (en,es). But now i need to edit the product information to put in the inputs fields, and for this i wish in my edit page get all the translated details (title, description), but for some reason, is returning me only one language, it doesnt return all the translated details from a specific product:

```
ex: return Product::where('id', '2')->get();
```

Somebody uses this package?

Comment: try doing like this `return Product::all()->where('id', '=', '2');`

Answer (score 0):

Just read the documentation. Therein is all that you need.

Some example:

```
$product = Product::where('id', 2)->get();
$product->translate('de')->title = "Germany title";
$product->translateOrNew('pl')->title = "Polish title";

//Shortcut
$product->{'title:pl'} = 'lorem ipsum';

$product->save(); //It Will save all translations and main model
```

Comment: $product = Product::where('id', 2)->get(); //only gives me the english, i need to get all languaes to be presenting in input fields

Comment: Do you have done whole installation and integration process of this package? ProductTranslation model exists? It is connected correctly with Product model?